# labeling roads / routes in KML

Tags: kml, labeling

According to [this post in 2008](http://groups.google.com/group/kml-support-getting-started/browse_thread/thread/0884266a603ce6a8) and others (older), there is no KML way to leverage the "labels to path" algorithms that Google Earth / Maps uses to put road names on the roads themselves.

Is this still the case? If so, are there other KML methods of labeling polylines or polygons that do not involve labeling a point within the line/gon... rather a general label for the entity itself?

Comment: Which software are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I highly suggest you to use Quantum GIS 1.7. They already release a latest version 1.7 codename: Wroclaw. This optimized software is suitable for labeling purposes. Since it is Free and Open Source, so it won't be much complexion. Download them here: http://qgis.org/

Regarding the problem, I find that maybe your KML is not 'perfect'. I mean the content. You must at least has a short description of it.

Good luck.

Comment: Welcome to our site, @zearth!  Thank you for being the first to offer an answer to this question.  But what are you really saying?  Are there "other KML methods of labeling polylines or polygons..." or not?

Comment: @whuber My pleasure is yours. Definitely. As for me, the simplest technique to create a KML file is using Google Earth. I'm sure most GIS specialists do the same. The labeling in QGIS is very easy, and we can choose the label we want dynamically.